# ¿Como leer vista procesada jsp en spring?

Tags: java, jsp, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

¿Existe la manera de obtener una vista como `String` ya procesada?

Necesito enviar correos y quiero evitar crear las vistas html en un `String` y mejor crear una vista JSP y poder llamarla como un `String`.

He tratado con `TemplateEngine` así:

```
import org.springframework.restdocs.templates.Template;
import org.springframework.restdocs.templates.TemplateEngine;

@Service
public class LectorVistas
{
    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public String obtenerVista(Model model, String vistaNombre) throws 
    IOException {
        Template vista = templateEngine.compileTemplate(vistaNombre);

        String view = vista.render(model.asMap());

        return view;
   }
}
```

Pero me genera una excepción:

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.restdocs.templates.LectorVistas] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency

¿Hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo?, ¿Cual es el error en mi código?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que necesitas hacer? Si necesitas enviar correo con formato HTML, no necesitas devolver una vista en absoluto. Puedes usar un template engine que te ayude a generar el contenido del correo como FreeMarker o Velocity. Ojo que estos no necesariamente van a trabajar con un JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que tomar en cuenta es que un JSP es un *servlet*. Debe pasar por todo el proceso para que se *renderice* como HTML.

Es decir, y dependiendo de las optimizaciones del motor de "traducción" de JSPs, si es la primera petición hacía ese JSP, entonces no hay archivo *class*. Luego el JSP es *traducido* a un archivo Java (*servlet*). En algunos servidores de aplicaciones es posible echar un vistazo a esos archivos generados. El archivo es compilado y la clase es cargada en memoria. Se crea una instancia del *servlet*. El contenedor despacha un hilo para manejar la petición HTTP con esta instancia. La respuesta es generada y enviada al navegador. El navegador interpreta la respuesta.<sup>**1**</sup>

Aunque es posible utilizar un motor de *servlets* embebido como Jetty para obtener el HTML resultante, quizás lo que conviene más en este caso es usar un motor de plantillas como Velocity<sup>**2**</sup> o FreeMarker<sup>**3**</sup>.

---

*Referencias*

1. Mahesh P. Matha. (2013). *JSP and Servlets: A Comprehensive Study*. India: Prentice-Hall. p. 17.
2. Hay un ejemplo en [Spring Email Velocity Template Example](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-email-velocity-template-example).
3. Hay un ejemplo en [Sending email with freemarker template](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-4-sending-email-with-freemarker-template).